# If Not Exists syntax MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simple insert query in MySQL

```
insert into eventimages (eventid, imageid) values (x, y)
```

which I want to amend so that the insert only happens if it isn't creating a duplicate row.
I'm guessing that somewhere I'd need to include something like

```
if not exists (select * from eventimages where eventid = x and imageid = y)
```

Can anyone help with the syntax.

Cheers

Comment: See INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX arbitrary_index_name ON eventimages (eventid, imageid);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "right" way to prevent duplicates is by putting a unique constraint/index on the column pair:

```
create unique index eventimages_eventid_imageid on eventimages(eventid, imageid);
```

Then this condition will always be guaranteed to be true.  A regular insert will fail, as will an `update` that create a duplicate.  Here are two ways to ignore such errors:

```
insert ignore into eventimages (eventid, imageid)
    values (x, y);
```

This will ignore *all* errors in the insert.  That might be overkill.  You can also do:

```
insert into eventimages(eventid, imageid)
    values (x, y)
    on duplicate key update eventid = x;
```

The `update` statement is a no-op.  The purpose is just to suppress a duplicate key error.

Comment: Cheers. Yes, I should have said that ignoring errors is important - x and y are actually Classic ASP form variables and my script loops through an array and runs the query three or four times (with different parameters obviously)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into eventimages (eventid, imageid)
select x,y
from dual
where not exists (select 1 
                  from eventimages 
                  where eventid = x and imageid = y)
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/070563/1

Comment: +1 . . . The answer didn't deserve to be downvoted in any case.

Answer (score 1):

could you try this:

```
 INSERT INTO eventimages (eventid, imageid)
Select * from (select x as eventid,y as imageid from eventimages) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select * from eventimages where eventid = x and imageid = y
) LIMIT 1;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f13de/1)

Comment: I've given the unique index answer the "win" but your method works so I've given you an upvote

Comment: @John as long as any answer works i would be glad :). thanks for the upvote :)