# I need to prevent duplicate data from being entered. I am basing on the following; first_name, last_name and tel

Tags: php, mysql

I need to have a function that checks for duplicate entries based on the following fields: first_name, last_name and tel
I have tried going through the forum but cant seem to find help.

```
<?
function do_data_entry($data){
global $conn;
$sql = "INSERT INTO entry_details (reg_type,mem_id,title,first_name,middle_name,last_name,address,tel,email,position,place_work,mem_cat,mem_fee,sub_date,next_date_sub,district,mem_status,mem_status_reason) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss',$reg_type,$mem_id,$title,$first_name,$middle_name,$last_name,$address,$tel,$email,$position,$place_work,$mem_cat,$mem_fee,$sub_date,$next_date_sub,$district,$mem_status,$mem_status_reason);
```

//This picks data posted from the code(in a different form below)

```
if(is_loggedIN() == 'user'){
redirect('../index.php');
}else if(is_loggedIN() == 'admin'){
if(isset($_POST['add_entry'])){
$data['reg_type'] = $_POST['reg_type'];
$data['mem_id'] = $_POST['mem_id'];
$data['title'] = $_POST['title'];
$data['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$data['middle_name'] = !isset($_POST['middle_name']) ? "" : $_POST['middle_name'];
$data['last_name'] = !isset($_POST['last_name']) ? "" : $_POST['last_name'];
$data['address'] = !isset($_POST['address']) ? "" : $_POST['address'];
$data['district'] = $_POST['district'];
$data['tel'] = !isset($_POST['tel']) ? "" : $_POST['tel'];
$data['email'] = !isset($_POST['email']) ? "" : $_POST['email'];
$data['position'] = !isset($_POST['position']) ? "" : $_POST['position'];
$data['place_work'] = !isset($_POST['place_work']) ? "" : $_POST['place_work'];
$data['mem_cat'] = $_POST['mem_cat'];
$data['mem_fee'] = $_POST['mem_fee'];
$data['sub_date'] = $_POST['sub_date'];
$data['next_date_sub'] = $_POST['next_date_sub'];
$data['mem_status'] = $_POST['mem_status'];
$data['mem_status_reason'] = $_POST['mem_status_reason'];
if(do_data_entry($data)){
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Entry created successfully";
        redirect('data_entry.php');
    }else{
        $_SESSION["message"] = "User already exists. Try different name";
    }
}
}else{
redirect('../login.php');
}
```

Comment: Here's a question I asked four years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196615/if-not-exists-syntax-mysql

Comment: try this create a function to check if the  firstname, lastname and tel are in the db by using this query, $query="SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `f_name`='fnameSubmitted' AND `l_name`='l_nameSubmitted' AND `tel'='telSubmitted'; then execute the query and use mysql_num_rows() to count howmany result was returned if >0  then the record exist else the record doesnt exist and you perform your logic

Comment: Thanks for this as well. I didnt know it was possible through MySQL. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple and straight solution is to make a primary key composed by first_name + last_name + tel columns.
After that when you will try to insert the exact same combination, the database (whatever would be) constraint will raise an error and insert will fail.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Another (poorer) solution could be:

Before you do the insert to access a stored sql function which will check for what you want.

The sql function should be something like that:

```
...
declare @someVariable int
select @someVariable = count(*) from table t 
where (t.FirstName = send_parameterFirstName) AND 
      (t.LasttName = send_parameterLastName) AND 
      (t.tel = send_parameterTel) 

if @someVariable > 0
  return -1 
else 
  return 1
....
```

If you get -1 you don't do the insert .... :)
Of course you should write your own code, but I still think that the primary key is the best solution and the second is just a poor solution.
You can see here how you can access a stored sql function from php:
[access sql functions from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798213/how-to-execute-a-sql-server-function-from-php)

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I need to do is; incase the first_name, middle_name and tel match, it shouldnt allow to post data to the database. I need a code to do just that.

Comment: I have edited my answer but the actually code you should write it :)
I still think the primary key is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes, I agree. A Primary key is the best solution. Let me try that out now.

Comment: I have been able to do it using PHPMyAdmin. I am so excited about the fact that the team on this website is so cooperative. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

After following the guidance I received from colleagues on my post, I went to the MySQL database using phpMyAdmin, opened the table structure that I wanted to apply the set rules on, selected the columns (first_name, last_name and tel), then below, i selected "Unique", it applied the changes, I selected the columns of my choice again and this time selected "Index". It now works exactly the way I wanted it. 
Thanks alot for your support members.